# Error compiling opencv_3.4.0 from source

Tags: cmake, opencv3.0, cmake-gui

I encountered the following error while trying to make opencv-3.4.0 from source:

```
main:StaticLib theo$ make -j8
[  0%] Built target gen-pkgconfig
[  1%] Built target ittnotify
[  3%] Built target zlib
[  5%] Built target gen_opencv_python_source
[  8%] Built target libjpeg
[ 14%] Built target ippiw
[ 15%] Built target libjasper
[ 17%] Built target libpng
[ 23%] Built target libtiff
[ 30%] Built target libprotobuf
[ 38%] Built target IlmImf
[ 45%] Built target opencv_core
[ 46%] Built target opencv_flann
[ 48%] Built target opencv_ml
[ 56%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 57%] Built target opencv_objdetect
[ 59%] Built target opencv_video
[ 60%] Built target opencv_photo
[ 68%] Built target opencv_dnn
[ 68%] Built target opencv_shape
[ 70%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 70%] Built target opencv_videoio
[ 70%] Built target opencv_highgui
[ 71%] Built target opencv_superres
[ 71%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_version
[ 71%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_annotation
[ 71%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_visualisation
ld: library not found for -lgstbase-1.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ld: library not found for -lgstbase-1.0
ld: library not found for -lgstbase-1.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_visualisation] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps/visualisation/CMakeFiles/opencv_visualisation.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_version] Error 1
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_annotation] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps/annotation/CMakeFiles/opencv_annotation.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [apps/version/CMakeFiles/opencv_version.dir/all] Error 2
[ 72%] Built target opencv_ts
[ 74%] Built target opencv_features2d
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I cannot find the package lgstbase-1.0 and am not sure how to link it to the project.

I encountered the same error with lintl, but I followed advice from another thread to fix it (brew reinstall gettext).

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to figure out what package provides the library `gstbase-1.0` and install it.  Google is probably your friend here.

Comment: I see. It is gstreamer apparently, which is installed and linked in my system, along with gst-plugins-base and gst-plugins-good.

Comment: How else can I troubleshoot this?